# Google Drive Api Pdf export from Google Doc generate empty response

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I'm using the export Google Drive API to retrieve a Google Doc as Pdf: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export

I'm having the following problem: for documents bigger than a certain size (I don't know exactly the threshold, but it happens even with relatively small files around 1,5 MB) the API return a 200 response code with a blank result (normally it should contains the pdf data as byte stream), as you can see in the following screenshot:
[image: export test screenshot]

I can successfully export the file via GoogleDrive/GoogleDoc UI  with the "File -> Download as.. -> Pdf" command, despite it takes a bit of time.

Here is the file used for test (1.180 KB exported from Google Doc), I shared it so you can access to try export:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/18Cz7kHfEiDLeTWHyyoOi6U4kFQDMeg0D-CCJzILMMCk/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the (Java) code I'm using to perform the operation:

```
@Override
public GoogleDriveDocumentContent downloadFileContentAsPDF(String executionGoogleUser, String fileId) {

    GoogleDriveDocumentContent documentContent = new GoogleDriveDocumentContent();

    String conversionMimeType = "application/pdf";

    try {

        getLogger().info("GDrive APIs - Downloading file content in PDF format ...");

        InputStream gDriveFileData = getDriveService(executionGoogleUser).files()
                .export(fileId, conversionMimeType)
                .executeMediaAsInputStream();

        getLogger().info("GDrive APIs - File content as PDF format downloaded.");

        documentContent.setFileName(null);
        documentContent.setMimeType(conversionMimeType);
        documentContent.setData(gDriveFileData);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return documentContent;

}
```

Does anyone has the same issue and know how to solve it?
The goal is to generate a pdf from a Google Doc.

Thanks

Comment: can you include the code you are using to preform the download?

Comment: Of course, I'm editing the question, however the same issue happens trying the api from the Google API documentation page: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export

Comment: Googles documentation page is not intended for use to download large files its for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using media downloadeder you will have to alter it for Google drive rather than storage service.

```
{
    // Create the service using the client credentials.
    var storageService = new StorageService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "APP_NAME_HERE"
        });
    // Get the client request object for the bucket and desired object.
    var getRequest = storageService.Objects.Get("BUCKET_HERE", "OBJECT_HERE");
    using (var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(
        "FILE_PATH_HERE",
        System.IO.FileMode.Create,
        System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
    {
        // Add a handler which will be notified on progress changes.
        // It will notify on each chunk download and when the
        // download is completed or failed.
        getRequest.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += Download_ProgressChanged;
        getRequest.Download(fileStream);
    }
}

static void Download_ProgressChanged(IDownloadProgress progress)
{
    Console.WriteLine(progress.Status + " " + progress.BytesDownloaded);
}
```

Code ripped from [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/media_download)

Comment: Ok thanks, but my goal is to generate a pdf from a Google Doc, not to download a big file. It could be fine even if the pdf is generated on drive instead of downloaded. Is there a solution in this way?

Comment: Not really because file.export is going to download the file it wont generate it On drive for you https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents  your going to have to reupload it after.

Comment: Yes I know, and this is what I already do. But the export api doesn't work for big files. And I can't use MediaDownloader to download a file that has not been yet generated. Do you know any other solutions?